# libgssapi_krb5.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, importerror, linux-mint, pyside2

I wanted to learn a bit of Qt and Python for a project, but when I was trying to setup pycharms for the project / run the project I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1042, in _handle_fromlist
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: libgssapi_krb5.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The actual program is the following:

```
import sys
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PySide2.QtUiTools import QUiLoader


def initApp():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    return app


def loadMainWindow():
    loader = QUiLoader()
    mainWindow = loader.load("UI/Main.ui", None)
    return mainWindow


def main():
    app = initApp()
    mainWindow = loadMainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I already tried reinstalling PySide2 and also deleted and recreated the whole venv, created a symlink to libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (which actualy exsits on the OS, which is LM 19.2)